# How to show two separate list in a crystal report?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports-2010

I want to show these two separate groups in one crystal report like this image.

Product and installment schedule are store in two tables in database as it is.  I try subreport / grouping/Section, but I failed. I couldn’t understand that, is this my logical or configuration mistake about crystal report.  Please anyone guide me. also I googled it but I did not find helpful result.

Thanks.

> Report like this:

[image: Report like this]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do this with a simple logic. you can create product sale report in one report and installment schedule for sale report in another report and you can merge this two reports in one single report using **sub report**. 
[check this link](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/07/subreports-in-crystal-reports-in-aspnet.html)